# Convert sql timestamp to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ

Tags: java, timestamp

I need to convert a SQL Server timestamp format (stored on Timestamp java data type) into this format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ (it's the date format parsed by Alfresco)

How can I do it?

thanks for your time!

Andrea

Comment: On which side exactly do you want to convert it to string? In the DB side or the presentation (UI) side? If UI, what UI technology are you using? What exactly do you mean "parsed by Alfresco"? Does it accept only `String` instead of `Date` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" );
String yourformattedDate = sdf.format(yourDate);
```

Comment: Great! I used sdf.parse instead of sdf.format that was the problem! Thanks Fred!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and get the time (in ms) from your TimeStamp instance, create a Date instance and use the DateFormatter class to format it anyway you want. That is, assuming DateFormatter supports the format you want.